# Trying to check if tuple item is nan

Tags: python, pandas

I have the below for loop and am try to check first if the tuple(row) item in position 10 is Nan

```
i=0
for row in df.iterrows():
    if row[1][10] != None:
        names = row[1][10].split(',')
        for name in names:
            df2.loc[i,:] = row[1][:]
            i=i+1
    else:
        i=i+1
```

I thought I could use `if row[1][10] != None:` but it doesnt seem to work, anyone know the solution?

Comment: Can you `print(df.sample(5).to_dict("list"))` and add it to your post with the matching expected output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can use `pd.isnull(row[1][10])`  instead of `if row[1][10] != None`.

#### Example:

```
i=0
for row in df.iterrows():
    if pd.isnull(row[1][10]):
        df2.loc[i,:] = row[1][:]
        i=i+1
    else:
        names = row[1][10].split(',')
        for name in names:
            df2.loc[i,:] = row[1][:]
            df2.loc[i,'name'] = name
            i=i+1
```

Also please do give feedback about this solution.

Comment: Thank you! I actually had to use pd.notnull but you put me in the right direction!